# Finding a Lyapunov function for a specific problem

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have tried for a long time to find a Lyapunov function for the specific problem

$$\begin{align} x' &= -x - 2y + xy^2 \\ y' &= 3x - 3y + y^3 \end{align}$$

Do you know any Lyapunov function what is going to work to determine the stability of the origin? According to a phase portrait produced by pplane the stability of the origin is asymptotically stable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

We have

$$
\cases{
3x \dot x = -3 x^2-6 x y + 3x^2y^2\\
2y \dot y = 6x y-6 y^2+2y^4
}
$$

and after addition

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(3x^2+2y^2) = -3x^2-6y^2+3x^2y^2+2y^4
$$

now there exist $\rho_m$ such that $x^2+y^2 < \rho_m^2$ makes

$$
-3x^2-6y^2+3x^2y^2+2y^4 < 0
$$

in fact, $\rho_m = 1$ suffices.